# How to write binary data to serial port in C#

Tags: c#, binary, serial-port

I try to write some binary data to the Serial Interface with C#:

```
0x02 0x81 0xF4 ...
```

This is a command for a remote device and must be transferred exactly like this. And here starts the Problem. When I use

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(Byte[] data, int Offset, int Size)
```

the data gets encoded (to ASCII,UTF-8 or whatever).And that's exactly I don't can need,since my remote device doesn't understand any Encoding.

**Is there a Workaround?**

Comment: Are you sure it gets encoded? How can sending a raw `byte` array get encoded unless the other end is doing it?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you expect on the line? A string as "0x02 0x81 0xF4" or the corresponding raw data? `SerialPort.Write` will certainly send raw data, unless you encode it before already. Beware that the raw-data is not printable.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are writing? I find what you describe very unlikely. Far more likely, IMO, is that the writing code is simply wrong...

Comment: How are you converting `0x02 0x81 0xF4 ...` to byte array being transmitted.. Are *you* converting above `string` to bytes using `Encoding.GetBytes`?

Comment: Do you mean `0x02 0x81 0xF4 ...` is a string?!? Or do you have the data in the form `new byte[] { 0x02, 0x81, 0xF4, ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
using System.IO.Ports;

public void TestSerialPort()
{
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort.Open();
byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
serialPort.Close();
}
```

Comment: As well the comments above have been write. Writing a byte array to the serial port doesn't encode the data. Sorry for missleading you here. It was my serial sniffer, which caused the encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved that exact problem like this:

```
// Update Relay
serialPort2.Close();
serialPort2.PortName="COM3";
serialPort2.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
serialPort2.BaudRate=9600;
serialPort2.DataBits=8;
serialPort2.Parity=Parity.None;
serialPort2.StopBits= StopBits.One; 
try {serialPort2.Open();
    serialPort2.Write("\u00a0\u0001\u0001\u00a2");
} catch {
    // Open Serial Port Failed
    label1.Text=label1.Text+ " Fail";
}
```

Jeff

Comment: Hi Jeff, this "almost works". It doesn't work for the characters between 0x80 and 0x9F, since the Encoding table is not linear there. Thanks for your help anyway, Stefan

Comment: Maybe you can select a different encoding that will work. I don't understand why there isn't a simple "binary" encoding. I used to be able to send any byte I wanted directly for Xmodem, etc.